# loading animation over jqGrid while loading

Tags: jqgrid, onpreinit

I have table that loads relatively un-aesthetically to say the least.

I am looking for way to have the a loading animation over the div that holds the table, as that is the problem, before it loads but I am not sure if jqgrid has the appropriate events.  I am looking for something like pre-load or pre-init, and then on-ready un-block or end the animation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AJAX to fill the grid, you can use [`$(yourgrid).ajaxStart(handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) to attach an event while loading data and [`$(yourgrid).ajaxStop(handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) to hide it. JQGrid have an option to set to not display loading message, `loadui`.

Comment: unfortunately I am not.  Is there a html loading event like pre init? or something else that I could latch into to hide the grid until jqGrid.LoadComplete?

Comment: Im using `gridComplete` option of jqgrid to catch the event after the grid completes loading data.

Comment: Right but I need an event that occurs well before the grid loads.